# A loop that asks for a certain amount of numbers and outputs the how many of them are even

Tags: java, loops

I need to write a program that asks for 20 numbers and outputs the amount of even numbers. I figured out the loop part (for-loop) but i don't have any idea how to collect the data if that makes any sense.
Here is the loop:

```
for (int num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
    System.out.println("Anna luku");
    num = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Take a look into the modulo operator.

Comment: In this code, you reuse `num` with the Scanner, so if you input 20, the loop will end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the numbers when you run the program you can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Write 20 numbers:");
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.print("Number " + i + ":");
        int temp =sc.nextInt(); //this waits for you to write an int
        if(temp%2==0)
            counter++;
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("Even numbers:" + counter);
}
```

i've tested it ant it works, keep in mind that you need to press enter after you write each number

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like this:

```
int count = 0;

for (int num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
    System.out.println("Anna luku");
    if (input.nextInt() % 2 == 0)
        count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator to check if a number is divisible by another number (in this case - by 2). Note, BTW, that your code overwrites the loop variable, which is probably not what you meant:

```
int evens = 0;
for (int  i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    num = input.nextInt(); 
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        evens++;
    }
}
System.out.prinf("You inputted %d even numbers%n", evens);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some thing like this ?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputs[] = new int[20];
    System.out.printf("Please enter %d numbers\n",inputs.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Enter value number "+(i+1));
        int value = input.nextInt();
        inputs[i]=value;
    }
```